# Check if a file given

Tags: php, xml, api

I created an API that need to be executed when a XML file was given.
But, I can't check if the file was given (via PUT method) or not.

Please help me.
Is there something wrong with my code? It's always return FALSE even I send a valid XML file.

```
$x = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents("php://input"))),1);

if(file_get_contents("php://input") !== FALSE)  /* I cant use this, why? */
{
    // return a valid XML message
}else{
    // return an invalid XML message
}
```

Comment: have you tried `!=`..?

Comment: damn, I forgot to try that. I read the php manual and it says that it can return FALSE but not always FALSE (FALSE or 0), so it says that I should use ===. thanks @DipeshParmar

Comment: `php://input` is not available with `enctype="multipart/form-data` if you are using it. Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: there you go you have your answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note:  A stream opened with `php://input` can only be read once; the
>   stream does not support seek operations. However, depending on the
>   SAPI implementation, it may be possible to open another php://input
>   stream and restart reading. This is only possible if the request body
>   data has been saved. Typically, this is the case for POST requests,
>   but not other request methods, such as PUT or PROPFIND.

so you need to do something like this

```
$postcontent=file_get_contents("php://input");
$x = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($postcontent)),1);
// I think the above line should be inside the if block

if($postcontent !== FALSE)  /* I cant use this, why? */
{
    // return a valid XML message
}else{
    // return an invalid XML message
}
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: Thanks for more references.

Answer (score 0):

`php://input` stream can only be read once by any method, so it returns an empty string for the second and subsequent calls no matter what. You should save to an intermediate variable first:

```
$post = file_get_contents("php://input")));

/* Use `!=` will make empty string be false too */
if( ($post != FALSE) && 
    ($x = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($post,1)) )  
{
    // return a valid XML message
}else{
    // return an invalid XML message
}
```

Comment: @AldryWijaya: Thanks, looks like the first bit got cut off when I copied it from my testing script. (Yes, I did test it.)

Comment: u're welcome. So the most important thing that I should remember is "stream can only be read once". thanks @yakatz.

Comment: @AldryWijaya There are specific situations when it will appear to work even if you call it more than once, for example with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` like what is generated by a `<form>`, but for a proper `PUT` of a file, it will not work (`curl -i -X PUT -d "<xml><abc ghi='jkl'>def</abc></xml>" http://localhost/test.php`).